# Push items in objects from array when match

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting, merge

I have an array and object of items, I want to check each item in that array if its path has that object name, I push it in that object array.

So far this is all good, now if no match found I want to create a new item based on that array item name and push it inside it!

All my attempts ending in duplicated value, I think I need a third object/array I just can't think it anymore

To explain better:

```
cList = {
  "rList": {
    "Significant": [
      {
        "Path": "Significant\\Significant Charts",
        "Name": "Charts"
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

and

```
SSList = {
  value: [
    {
      "Name": "Test long name",
      "Path": "/someFolder/Test long name",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Untitled",
      "Path": "/Significant/Untitled",
    }
  ]
};
```

My current code

```
for (var cFolder in this.cList.rList) {
        this.SSList.forEach((ssFile)=> {
          if(ssFile.Path.indexOf(cFolder) >= 0){
            this.cList.rList[cFolder].push(ssFile);
          }
        });
      }
```

The first item in SSList will not be pushed since it doesn't match, I want to create a array and push it to inside rList

```
var folderName = ssFile.Path.split("/");
this.cList.rList[folderName[1]].push(ssFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to flip your inner and outer loops

```
let found = false;
this.SSList.value.forEach((ssFile) => {
    for (var cFolder in this.cList.rList) {
        if(ssFile.Path.indexOf(cFolder) >= 0){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        this.cList.rList[cFolder].push(ssFile);
    } else {
        folderName = ssFile.Path.split("/");
        if (!(folderName[1] in this.cList.rList))
            this.cList.rList[folderName[1]] = [];
        this.cList.rList[folderName[1]].push(ssFile);
    }
    found = false;
});
```